# s4sdk - MTA build throwing error in Jenkins

Tags: s4sdk

I am developing MTA project and have to integrate CI/CD for Cloud Foundry using s4sdk-pipeline however Jenkins fails to build the node project. Showing below error in Jenkins log

```
SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 1.1.8

Module "ProjectName": invoking npm

ERROR: An unexpected error has occurred; please tell us about it in our Community page:  

---------------------------------------------------------

--- ERROR OCCURRED IN LIBRARY STEP: mtaBuild

----------------------------------------------------------



FOLLOWING PARAMETERS WERE AVAILABLE TO THIS STEP:

***

[script:Script1@ee5197a]

***


ERROR WAS:

***

hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1

***


FURTHER INFORMATION:

* Documentation of library step mtaBuild: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/steps/mtaBuild/

* Source code of library step mtaBuild: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/blob/master/vars/mtaBuild.groovy

* Library documentation: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/

* Library repository: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library


----------------------------------------------------------

--- END LIBRARY STEP: mtaBuild ---

script returned exit code 1
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[screen capture: Jenkins Log Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2UQ.jpg)
as mentioned please see below Console Output log

```
Skipping 6 KB.. Full Log
PYMCpDfOQzp/bUe1sxGHFaM0ojAAAApx+LCAAAAAAAAP9tjTEOwjAUQ3+LOrAycohUCDbE1DXKwglCE0La6P/yk9JOnIircQdaKjHhwbItWe/1hiIynIidaCy2HmPtRRd6NyUxELfXQINo6CJqwkjBCmUHRcZWS1WULCzKclhJWFusA0WPLsFGNvqhy6DRlefE03aUkHtzhydkciInzelbRobtrTeR8Mf5C4CxS5Dv9rMd5mfxAbNWnxXCAAAA[0m[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Init)
[Pipeline] milestone
07:40:42 Trying to pass milestone 10
[Pipeline] library
07:40:42 Loading library s4sdk-pipeline-library@master
07:40:42 Attempting to resolve master from remote references...
07:40:42  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:42  > git ls-remote -h https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib.git # timeout=10
07:40:42 Found match: refs/heads/master revision a8a2909dadaff3c66b5008374e957a87509818ec
07:40:42 No credentials specified
07:40:42  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
07:40:42 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
07:40:42  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib.git # timeout=10
07:40:42 Fetching without tags
07:40:42 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib.git
07:40:42  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:42  > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
07:40:42 Checking out Revision a8a2909dadaff3c66b5008374e957a87509818ec (master)
07:40:42  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
07:40:42  > git checkout -f a8a2909dadaff3c66b5008374e957a87509818ec
07:40:42 Commit message: "Prepare for new piper library name"
07:40:42  > git rev-list --no-walk a8a2909dadaff3c66b5008374e957a87509818ec # timeout=10
[Pipeline] library
07:40:45 Loading library piper-library-os@def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453
07:40:45 Attempting to resolve def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453 from remote references...
07:40:45  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:45  > git ls-remote -h https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git # timeout=10
07:40:46 Could not find def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453 in remote references. Pulling heads to local for deep search...
07:40:46  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
07:40:46 Setting origin to https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git
07:40:46  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git # timeout=10
07:40:46 Fetching origin...
07:40:46 Fetching upstream changes from origin
07:40:46  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:46  > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
07:40:46  > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
07:40:46  > git rev-parse def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453^{commit} # timeout=10
07:40:46  > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453 # timeout=10
07:40:46 Selected match: cst revision def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453
07:40:46 No credentials specified
07:40:46  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
07:40:46 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
07:40:46  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git # timeout=10
07:40:46 Fetching without tags
07:40:46 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git
07:40:46  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:46  > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
07:40:46 Checking out Revision def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453 (cst)
07:40:46  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
07:40:47  > git checkout -f def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453
07:40:47 Commit message: "extend Analytics (#439)"
07:40:47  > git rev-list --no-walk def66f4ffa9e614eeb3747599a0be7ea9a108453 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:47 Sending telemetry data is disabled.
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:47 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: initS4sdkPipeline.groovy ---
[Pipeline] node
07:40:47 Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/projectui_PR-1@3
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:47 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: unstashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:47 Unstashing []
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:47 --- END LIBRARY STEP: unstashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] checkout
07:40:48 using credential JDNew
07:40:48 Cloning the remote Git repository
07:40:48 Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
07:40:48 Cloning repository https://github.com/.../l....git
07:40:48  > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/projectui_PR-1@3 # timeout=10
07:40:48 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/.../l....git
07:40:48  > git --version # timeout=10
07:40:48 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
07:40:48  > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/.../l....git +refs/pull/1/head:refs/remotes/origin/PR-1 +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
07:40:49  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/.../l....git # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull/1/head:refs/remotes/origin/PR-1 # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/.../l....git # timeout=10
07:40:49 Fetching without tags
07:40:49 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/.../l....git
07:40:49 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
07:40:49  > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/.../l....git +refs/pull/1/head:refs/remotes/origin/PR-1 +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
07:40:49 Merging remotes/origin/master commit 28f2a2d55051a061c9aaec44b2b697822b8378de into PR head commit 567cacb5d338b222a318166d6570948ffe0162af
07:40:49  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git checkout -f 567cacb5d338b222a318166d6570948ffe0162af
07:40:49  > git merge 28f2a2d55051a061c9aaec44b2b697822b8378de # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
07:40:49 Merge succeeded, producing 567cacb5d338b222a318166d6570948ffe0162af
07:40:49 Checking out Revision 567cacb5d338b222a318166d6570948ffe0162af (PR-1)
07:40:49  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
07:40:49  > git checkout -f 567cacb5d338b222a318166d6570948ffe0162af
07:40:49 Commit message: "changed"
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:49 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: initS4SdkPipelineLibrary.groovy ---
[Pipeline] library
07:40:49 Only using first definition of library piper-library-os
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:49 Sending telemetry data is disabled.
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: setupCommonPipelineEnvironment ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 Loading configuration file 'default_pipeline_environment.yml'
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 Loading configuration file 'default_s4_pipeline_environment.yml'
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- END LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- END LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:50 --- END LIBRARY STEP: setupCommonPipelineEnvironment ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:51 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: checkDiskSpace.groovy ---
[Pipeline] sh
07:40:51 + df -m /var/jenkins_home
07:40:51 + awk FNR > 1 {print $4}
[Pipeline] sh
07:40:52 + du -md 0 /var/jenkins_home/jobs/projectui/branches/PR-1/builds/18
07:40:52 + awk {print $1}
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:52 --- END LIBRARY STEP: checkDiskSpace.groovy ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:52 Download cache for maven and npm activated
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:52 --- END LIBRARY STEP: initS4SdkPipelineLibrary.groovy ---
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:52 Stash config: [initS4sdkPipeline:[unstash:[], stashes:[[name:SOURCE, includes:**/*.*, excludes:'pipelines/**, **/.git/**], [name:PIPELINE, includes:'pipelines/**, excludes:'pipelines/.git/**], [name:REPORTS, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**], [name:M2, includes:s4hana_pipeline/maven_local_repo/**], [name:TARGET, includes:**/target/**], [name:NODE_MODULES, includes:node_modules/**]]], build:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2], stashes:[[name:M2, includes:s4hana_pipeline/maven_local_repo/**], [name:TARGET, includes:*.mtar, **/target/**, target/**], [name:NODE_MODULES, includes:**/node_modules/**, node_modules/**], [name:PACKAGE_LOCK, includes:**/package-lock.json, **/npm-shrinkwrap.json]]], unitTests:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, TARGET], stashes:[[name:REPORTS, merge:true, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**]]], integrationTests:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, TARGET], stashes:[[name:REPORTS, merge:true, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**]]], staticCodeChecks:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET, REPORTS, M2], stashes:[[name:REPORTS, merge:true, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**]]], lint:[unstash:[SOURCE, NODE_MODULES, PACKAGE_LOCK]], checkmarxScan:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET, REPORTS, M2], stashes:[]], whitesourceScan:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], sourceClearScan:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], additionalTools:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], fortifyScan:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2], stashes:[]], npmAudit:[unstash:[SOURCE, PACKAGE_LOCK], stashes:[]], frontendUnitTests:[unstash:[SOURCE, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], endToEndTests:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], performanceTests:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET], stashes:[[name:REPORTS, merge:true, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**]]], s4SdkQualityChecks:[unstash:[SOURCE, M2, TARGET, REPORTS], stashes:[[name:REPORTS, includes:s4hana_pipeline/reports/**]]], artifactDeployment:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]], productionDeployment:[unstash:[SOURCE, TARGET, NODE_MODULES], stashes:[]]]
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:53 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: errorWhenCurrentBuildResultIsWorseOrEqualTo.groovy ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:53 --- END LIBRARY STEP: errorWhenCurrentBuildResultIsWorseOrEqualTo.groovy ---
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
07:40:54 nodejs has modules:  projectui
[Pipeline] sh
07:40:54 + git rev-parse HEAD
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:02 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: stashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 105 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 0 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 0 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 0 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 1 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
07:41:03 Stashed 0 file(s)
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:03 --- END LIBRARY STEP: stashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:03 Current build result in stage initS4sdkPipeline is SUCCESS.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:03 Sending telemetry data: [event_type:pipeline_stage, custom3:stage_name, e_3:initS4sdkPipeline, custom4:stage_result, e_4:SUCCESS, custom5:start_time, e_5:1549957247815, custom6:duration, e_6:15979, custom7:project_extensions, e_7:false, custom8:global_extensions, e_8:false, action_name:SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK, idsite:70aeb424-0d69-0265-c486-b5471b014ba8, idsitesub:pipeline, url:https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/tree/master/doc/operations/analytics.md, custom2:project_id_hash, e_2:75174568523be69fb6d03f76d4bd9263f70a5e265d4374c4eca2bc6994a06ea0, custom1:build_url_hash, e_a:317b74bc0b282598de984862589c9b33f4bf1864, custom10:build_number, e_10:19]
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:04 --- END LIBRARY STEP: initS4sdkPipeline.groovy ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:05 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: abortOldBuilds.groovy ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:05 --- END LIBRARY STEP: abortOldBuilds.groovy ---
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] milestone
07:41:05 Trying to pass milestone 20
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:05 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: build.groovy ---
[Pipeline] node
07:41:05 Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/projectui_PR-1@3
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:05 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: unstashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:05 Unstashing [SOURCE, M2]
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:06 --- END LIBRARY STEP: unstashFiles.groovy ---
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:07 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: mtaBuild ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:07 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:07 --- END LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:08 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: dockerExecute ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:08 --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:08 --- END LIBRARY STEP: prepareDefaultValues ---
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:09 + docker ps -q
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:09 [INFO][dockerExecute] Running on local environment.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:09 Java home '/docker-java-home' retrieved from environment.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:09 Verifying Java location '/docker-java-home'.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:10 + set +x
07:41:10 /docker-java-home exists.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:10 + set +x
07:41:10 /docker-java-home is a directory.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:10 + set +x
07:41:10 /docker-java-home is not empty.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:10 Verification success. Java location '/docker-java-home' exists.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:11 Verifying Java '/docker-java-home/bin/java'.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:12 + set +x
07:41:12 /docker-java-home/bin/java exists.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:12 + set +x
07:41:12 /docker-java-home/bin/java is a file.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:12 Verification success. Java '/docker-java-home/bin/java' exists.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:13 Verifying Java version 1.8.0 or compatible version.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:13 Verification success. Java version 1.8.0 is installed.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:13 Verifying SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 'mta.jar'.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:14 + set +x
07:41:14 mta.jar exists.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:14 + set +x
07:41:14 mta.jar is a file.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:14 Verification success. SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 'mta.jar' exists.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:15 Verifying SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder version 1.0.6 or compatible version.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:16 Verification success. SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder version 1.1.8 is installed.
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:16 [INFO] 'mta.yaml' file found in project sources.
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:16 + date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
07:41:16 + sed -ie s/${timestamp}/20190212074116/g mta.yaml
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:16 SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder file 'mta.jar' retrieved from configuration.
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:17 Using SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 'mta.jar'.
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:17 [INFO] Executing mta build call: '/docker-java-home/bin/java -jar mta.jar --mtar projectui.mtar --build-target=CF build'.
[Pipeline] sh
07:41:18 SAP Multitarget Application Archive Builder 1.1.8
07:41:18 Module "projectui": invoking npm
07:41:18 ERROR: An unexpected error has occurred; please tell us about it in our Community page: " https://answers.sap.com/tags/73554900100700001351"
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 --- ERROR OCCURRED IN LIBRARY STEP: dockerExecute
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 
07:41:18 FOLLOWING PARAMETERS WERE AVAILABLE TO THIS STEP:
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 [script:Script1@ee5197a, dockerImage:null, dockerOptions:null]
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 
07:41:18 ERROR WAS:
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 
07:41:18 FURTHER INFORMATION:
07:41:18 * Documentation of library step dockerExecute: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/steps/dockerExecute/
07:41:18 * Source code of library step dockerExecute: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/blob/master/vars/dockerExecute.groovy
07:41:18 * Library documentation: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/
07:41:18 * Library repository: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library
07:41:18 
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 --- END LIBRARY STEP: dockerExecute ---
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 --- ERROR OCCURRED IN LIBRARY STEP: mtaBuild
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 
07:41:18 FOLLOWING PARAMETERS WERE AVAILABLE TO THIS STEP:
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 [script:Script1@ee5197a]
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 
07:41:18 ERROR WAS:
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
07:41:18 ***
07:41:18 
07:41:18 FURTHER INFORMATION:
07:41:18 * Documentation of library step mtaBuild: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/steps/mtaBuild/
07:41:18 * Source code of library step mtaBuild: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/blob/master/vars/mtaBuild.groovy
07:41:18 * Library documentation: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/
07:41:18 * Library repository: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library
07:41:18 
07:41:18 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:18 --- END LIBRARY STEP: mtaBuild ---
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:18 Sending telemetry data: [event_type:pipeline_stage, custom3:stage_name, e_3:build, custom4:stage_result, e_4:SUCCESS, custom5:start_time, e_5:1549957265764, custom6:duration, e_6:13028, custom7:project_extensions, e_7:false, custom8:global_extensions, e_8:false, action_name:SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK, idsite:70aeb424-0d69-0265-c486-b5471b014ba8, idsitesub:pipeline, url:https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/tree/master/doc/operations/analytics.md, custom2:project_id_hash, e_2:75174568523be69fb6d03f76d4bd9263f70a5e265d4374c4eca2bc6994a06ea0, custom1:build_url_hash, e_a:317b74bc0b282598de984862589c9b33f4bf1864, custom10:build_number, e_10:19]
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:19 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:19 --- ERROR OCCURRED IN LIBRARY STEP: build
07:41:19 ----------------------------------------------------------
07:41:19 
07:41:19 FOLLOWING PARAMETERS WERE AVAILABLE TO THIS STEP:
07:41:19 ***
07:41:19 [:]
07:41:19 ***
07:41:19 
07:41:19 ERROR WAS:
07:41:19 ***
07:41:19 hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
07:41:19 ***
07:41:19 
07:41:19 
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:19 --- END LIBRARY STEP: build.groovy ---
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Artifact Deployment)
Stage "Artifact Deployment" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Production Deployment)
Stage "Production Deployment" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:20 Sending telemetry data: [custom11:os_name, e_11:Linux, custom12:os_version, e_12:4.15.0-1032-aws, custom13:swa_schema_version, e_13:1, locale:C.UTF-8, custom7:jenkins_version, e_7:2.150.1, custom9:is_productive, e_9:false, event_type:pipeline, custom3:stage_name, e_3:postAction, custom4:pipeline_result, e_4:FAILURE, custom5:start_time, e_5:1549957239642, custom6:pipeline_duration, e_6:40344, action_name:SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK, idsite:70aeb424-0d69-0265-c486-b5471b014ba8, idsitesub:pipeline, url:https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/tree/master/doc/operations/analytics.md, custom2:project_id_hash, e_2:75174568523be69fb6d03f76d4bd9263f70a5e265d4374c4eca2bc6994a06ea0, custom1:build_url_hash, e_a:317b74bc0b282598de984862589c9b33f4bf1864, custom10:build_number, e_10:19]
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:20 Hello World 
[Pipeline] echo
07:41:22 Hello World--1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

screenshot of local build  [local build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rspj.jpg)

Comment: Hi, it looks like the mta build tool throws an error, I'm not sure how we in the pipeline can fix this. Does it work to build the project locally using the mta builder? If yes, which version do you use? Which Docker image do you use for the mta builder in the pipeline? Also, can you elaborate on the project (files/folders) structure?

Comment: Hi Florian,
Thanks for your reply. Yes I am able to build the project locally and deploy using CF command however now I want to automate the process.

on AWS instance have installed https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib cx serve instance to run Jenkins which build the Java project perfectly fine however need build the UI project with MTA. which is failing on build stage.  

Not sure if I need to provide Docker image in Jenkins configuration.

Comment: Folders in Git
 - ProjectFolder
 - target
 - .gitignore
 - Jenkinsfile
 - README.md
 - mta.jar
 - mta.yaml
 - package-lock.json
 - pipeline_config.yml
 - xs-security.json

Comment: As described here https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#mtabuild a image must be provided in the pipeline_config.yml file, so I assume you have one there, otherwise your pipeline would not get thus far. 

As the error message from the mta archive builder says nothing, I don't really know how we can help.

Comment: Another question: Did you cut any log output? The output of the mta builder looks incomplete. Be of course sure to not post any confidential info, but I'm wondering if there is not more helpful output.

Comment: Please check the screenshot added in the main comments for your reference. Could you please provide a sample of docker image to build the UI project as I am assuming my docker image is failing here or any reference blog to build UI project using MTA for CF in Jenkins. Thanks

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but this docker image should in theory work https://github.com/SAP/devops-docker-images/tree/master/mta-archive-builder

The screenshot is sadly not too helpful because all the log messages are collapsed

Comment: please check the log added in the main comment

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to help here, sorry. This does not look like an error in the pipeline. Please do what the output says 

> 07:41:18 ERROR: An unexpected error has occurred; please tell us about it in our Community page: " https://answers.sap.com/tags/73554900100700001351"

Comment: Are you able to build the project locally with the mta build? which version are you using locally?

Comment: Yes Daniel, I am able to build the project locally. and my Multi target Archive Builder version is 1.1.8.

Comment: Hi Daniel I have added screenshot of CMD window of local build

Comment: Would you mind creating a minimal example on GitHub? Since we don't have expressive log output, reproducing the issue ourselves would maybe help to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log output says:
`[INFO][dockerExecute] Running on local environment.`. That means that either Docker is not installed or no Docker image is defined. Thus, it tries to build the mta in the local environment which potentially does not have all requirements installed. (E.g. no nodejs installation.)

Please add the following configuration to your pipeline configuration (`pipeline_config.yml`) in order to configure the Docker image which should be used:

```
steps:
  mtaBuild:
    mtaJarLocation: '/opt/sap/mta/lib/mta.jar'
    dockerImage: 'ppiper/mta-archive-builder'
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, After adding the correct docker image my pipeline is now able to build the MTA.